# Overhead of large length in PHP stream_get_line()

Tags: php, performance, sockets, stream

I'm testing out a PHP library which relies upon another streams based library.  My experience is with sockets which is low level compared to streams so I'm a little unsure if streams is going to be flexible enough.

Basically, using sockets, I would write a buffer loop which checked each chunk of data for an EOL character like `\n` like so...

PHP

```
$data = NULL;
while ($buffer = socket_read($connection,1024)) {
    $data .= $buffer;
    if (strpos($buffer, "\n") !== FALSE) {
        $data = substr($data,0,-1);
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm looking to do something similar without having to rewrite their entire library.  Here's the problem...

`stream_get_line($handle,$length,$EOL)` accepts a length value but will truncate everything longer than that.  PHP docs state...

> Reading ends when length bytes have been read, when the string specified by ending is found (which is not included in the return value), or on EOF (**whichever comes first**).

... and there's no offset param so I can't use it the same way to get the remainder.  This means that if I don't know the length of the data, or if it's inconsistent, I need to set `length` high enough to deal with ANY possible length of data.

That isn't the big concern, that seems to work. The question is **will setting the `$length` value to something like `512000` (500Kb) cause a lot of unnecessary overhead for shorter responses?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the statement from the docs:

> Reading ends when length bytes have been read, when the string
>   specified by ending is found (which is not included in the return
>   value), or on EOF (whichever comes first).

This doesn't mean that if you pass a length of 1,024 or even 200,000 and the line is longer than that the rest of the data is truncated or lost.  This is just the maximum amount of data the call will return if it doesn't reach EOF/EOL before that.

So if you have a line that is 102,500 bytes long and you have the length parameter set to 1024, you will have to have called `stream_get_line` 101 times before the entire line of data is read **but the entire line will be read**, just not in one call to the function.

To directly answer your question, there won't be any extra overhead for short responses if you pass a large value.  How it works under the hood really depends on what type of stream you are reading from.  In the case of a network stream with a large `length` value, it may take a long time before the call returns any data in the event that it takes a long time for `length` data to be read from the network, where if you were reading in smaller chunks, you might start to get more data from the network before everything has been received.

Comment: I see, I'd assumed that the stream would be dropped on the first pass, didn't realize it operated essentially like socket_read().  So does that mean I could essentially drop in `stream_get_line($connection,1024,"\n")` in place of `socket_read($connection,1024)` in my example and rather than look for `\n`, break on the first empty `$buffer`, or $buffer shorter than 1024 bytes?

Comment: .... or since `stream_get_line()` strips the EOL from the string automatically, it would just return `null` ending the while loop...

Comment: what type of stream are you trying to read?  stream_get_line returns false on error (trying to read after EOF), but will block on a network stream if no more data is available so you might need some application logic to determine EOF depending on what youre trying to read

Comment: It's a network stream coming from HandlerSocket, so I'm going to have to rework the break. Any suggestion as to how to do that?  With sockets it sufficed just to read the response for the EOL char and break, but if this is going to block and wait for more data before continuing, I'm not sure how to break that other than I'm assuming a timeout, which wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: This is a good description of the problem with detecting if the data continues... http://www.linuxonly.nl/docs/41/130_The_problem_with_stream_get_line.html

Comment: If you are reading a network stream that doesn't close the socket when all data has been sent (e.g. HTTP with connection: close), then determining at which point all data has been read is determined by whatever application protocol you are using.  For example, HTTP 1.1 with keep-alive and chunked transport will deliver data in chunks preceded by sizes in hexadecimal with the last chunk being 0 size.  HTTP 1.1 with keep alive and gzip encoding will return a content-length header telling you how long the response is.  Once that may bytes is read you are at EOF for that data.

Comment: So in short, how to rework the break depends on what application protocol you are communicating with as EOF will be different for all of them.

Comment: Handlersocket is TCP based, but it is a proprietary protocol used specifically for nosql style access to InnoDB tables in MySQL.  Unfortunately nothing as simple as a content length header, it simply sends a "\n" character to signal the end of the stream.  Since stream_read_line strips off EOL chars automatically and blocks otherwise, it sounds like it's not well suited to this task.

Comment: Maybe not.  Anything stopping you from using fread instead?  I looked at the HandlerSocket protocol quickly, and it does appear to be a line based protocol.  I'm wondering what happens if a record returned contains a \n character, is it escaped somehow or encoded?  This will impact how you write your code for detecting \n as a response delimeter.

Comment: Basically all control chars are encoded, the format is a dead simple tab delimited row with a basic order syntax.  As far as fread, I may as well use the code for sockets I already have, I'm pretty sure the resource $handle is compatible all the way around.  I'll have to test it out. Really appreciate your earlier info, really helpful, I'll go ahead and accept this answer and will update the original question with any details for a solution, might help someone else make a better call ;)